# How to use EnableDelayedExpansion in a FOR /L?

Tags: batch-file

I keep getting the error Missing Operator. I think i'm using "!" completely wrong but I don't know where to use it.

```
ECHO ON

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET CSV_Name=
SET /P CSV_Name=Please enter the CSV Name.

ECHO Zahl;Quadrat;Kubik >> C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\%CSV_Name%.csv

SET Square=0
SET Cubic=0
FOR /L  %%A IN (2, 2, 100) DO (
 SET /A !Square! = %%A * %%A
 SET /A !Cubic! = %%A * %%A * %%A
 ECHO %%A
 ECHO !Square!
 ECHO %%A;!Square!;!Cubic! >> C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\%CSV_Name%.csv
 )
```

Can someone explain what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
 SET /A Square = %%A * %%A
 SET /A Cubic = %%A * %%A * %%A
```

you don't need `!` or `%` when setting a new value to a variable.

Comment: That doesnt't work. I get for example. `SET /A Square = 70 * 70 ECHO !Square!`

Comment: @HenS - what you mean by not working? Is this in the output or the error is there again?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET /A !Square! = %%A * %%A
```

will attempt to set a variable named (the *contents* of `square`)

```
SET /A Square = %%A * %%A
```

will set `square`.

`!var!` will retrieve the *current* contents of the variable `var` (ie. as it changes due to the operation of the loop) whereas `%var%` will retrieve the *initial* value of the variable - as it stood when the statement was checked for validity ("parsed"). Outside of a loop, `!var!` = `%var%` but it's conventional wisdom to use `%var%` and reserve `!var!` for a value that *may* change during the operation of a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of lines).